# Probability that a driver will get a ticket for parking x mins over the time limit

Tags: probability

Suppose Joe is driving around Las Vegas, looking for a parking spot. He plans to stay in the area for exactly 2 hours and 20 minutes. He comes across a free parking spot that only allows parking for 2 hours. Knowing the parking enforcement officer only comes around once every 2 hours - every time marking cars that weren't there the last time the officer was there, and ticketing those cars if they are still there - Joe decides to take a gamble and park in that spot. Assuming Joe is equally likely to have arrived anytime within 2 hours since the officer's last visit, what is the probability that Joe will receive a ticket?

Edit: Answer redacted.

Comment: Sounds as simple as $\frac{20}{120}$ (the probability to get a ticket).

Comment: I feel like the probability for Joe to get a ticket is equal to the probability that he parks at the spot when there have gone less than $\frac{1}{3}$ hours from the point in time when the officer was last at the spot, because then the officer would have time to come back before Joe leaves. But I feel a bit perplexed about how to interpret that result because it involves an inequality and not an equality...

Comment: I think Joe will get a ticket if $y\ge4$, so $x\ge\frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: @user84413 Why do you set $x \geq \frac{5}{3}$ and not $x > \frac{5}{3}$ ?  If $x = \frac{5}{3}$ then the officer will arrive to the spot at the same time as Joe leaves, but how do you interpret that? Can the officer ticket Joe at the moment he leaves? I feel like one event would necessary need to happen before the other because they contradict eachother.

Comment: @hampadampadoo You're right that this is a matter of interpretation, but it doesn't affect his probability of receiving a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution.

Let x be the time, in minutes, between the officer's last visit to the spot and Joe's parking there. Therefore, in order for Joe to get a ticket, the officer must arrive twice - once at or before $x$, and again at or before $x + 140$. So, $x \le 120$ and $x + 140 \ge 240$. Solving the second inequality, we get: $x \ge 100 $

So, $100 \le x \le 120$. Therefore, there is a 20-minute block within which Joe must arrive to get a ticket. The probability of him doing so is $20/120$, or $1/6$.

Edit: It might help to think about a number line.